# Light Gallery is not initiating

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, lightgallery

Hi I have used this code to initialise still Light Gallery is not initiating

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.lightgallery').each(function(i, v) {
    $(v).lightGallery({
      thumbnail: false
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

You can check the live link below : https://cutt.ly/KjFeHkO

Comment: I can see that you are loading `lightgallery-all.min.js` before you load `jquery`. So that is the problem.

Comment: Hi @CarstenLøvboAndersen , Just reload the page i have made it the change still its not working

Comment: When I reload you page, you are still loading lightgallery before jquery

Comment: Don't link to any external resource, create a snippet here where we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: This is the error i am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined